# jQuery Gmap3 set marker active on click while other markers set to default

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to do a simple set a marker active when the user clicks on a marker. I am trying to use Gmap3's tag capability to keep track on what marker has been clicked on, so if another marker is clicked, the previous marker can be returned to its previous state.

Here is a fiddle which explains what I am trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/sidouglas/tKnsG/
EDIT 2: jsfiddle ( PEBKAC )

The crux is what is happening on the click event:

```
           events: {
                    click: function (marker, event, context) {

                       // this section does not work, as the tag 'notActive'
                       // has not been set to isActive
                       var activeMarkers = Map.gmap3({
                                       get: {
                                           name:'marker',
                                           all : true,
                                           tag : 'isActive'
                                       }
                                    });

                       for( var i in activeMarkers ){
                        var activeMarker = activeMarkers[i];
                        activeMarker.setOptions({
                                icon: 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=A|374D7E|FFFFFF'
                        });
                       }

                      // Set the icon as active.
                      // Need to set this tag as 'isActive' 
                      var letter = context.tag[0];
                      marker.setOptions({
                         icon : 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=' + letter + '|FFFFFF|000000'
                      });
                      // marker.somehowSetTag({ tag:[letter,'isActive']});

                    }
                }
```

Solution:

```
    (function ($) {
    $(function () {
        var Map = $('#map');
        Map.init = function (data) {
            Map.postData = data;
            Map.gmap3({
                map: {
                    options: {
                        center: [13.752222, 100.493889],
                        zoom: 4
                    }
                },
                marker: {
                    values: [
                        {id: 1, address:"Lopburi",   tag:['A'], options:{
                          icon: '//chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=A|374D7E|FFFFFF'

                        }},
                        {id: 2, address:"Koh Samui", tag:['B'], options:{
                          icon: '//chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=B|374D7E|FFFFFF'
                        }},
                        {id: 3, address:"Chaingmai", tag:['C'], options:{
                          icon: '//chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=C|374D7E|FFFFFF'
                        }}
                    ],
                    options: {
                        draggable: false
                    },
                    events: {
                        click: function (marker, event, context) {

                            var currentMarker = Map.currentMarker || false;

                            if( currentMarker ){
                                currentMarker.setOptions({
                                    icon: currentMarker.icon.replace('|FFFFFF|000000','|374D7E|FFFFFF')
                                });
                            }                         

                          var letter = context.tag[0];
                          marker.setOptions({
                             icon : '//chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=' + letter + '|FFFFFF|000000'
                          });

                          Map.currentMarker = marker;

                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        };
        Map.init();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the state of your tag and toggle between states.

pseudo code

```
if(tag==notActive){
    tag = isActive;
    code for isActive marker
}else{
    tag = notActive;
    code for notActive marker 
}
```

Comment: Yes, I understand what you are saying but I am looking for the means to set the tag. I am not sure if the gmap3 plugin for jQuery has a way to do this.

Comment: See this [DEMO](http://gmap3.net/en/pages/19-demo/) The second one with `var clear = {name:"marker"};` etc. This may help

Comment: The author responded that the tag can't be changed once set. I refactored the code, and in the end it was pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
    (function ($) {
    $(function () {
        var Map = $('#map');
        Map.init = function (data) {
            Map.postData = data;
            Map.gmap3({
                map: {
                    options: {
                        center: [13.752222, 100.493889],
                        zoom: 4
                    }
                },
                marker: {
                    values: [
                        {id: 1, address:"Lopburi",   tag:['A'], options:{
                          icon: '//chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=A|374D7E|FFFFFF'

                        }},
                        {id: 2, address:"Koh Samui", tag:['B'], options:{
                          icon: '//chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=B|374D7E|FFFFFF'
                        }},
                        {id: 3, address:"Chaingmai", tag:['C'], options:{
                          icon: '//chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=C|374D7E|FFFFFF'
                        }}
                    ],
                    options: {
                        draggable: false
                    },
                    events: {
                        click: function (marker, event, context) {

                            var currentMarker = Map.currentMarker || false;

                            if( currentMarker ){
                                currentMarker.setOptions({
                                    icon: currentMarker.icon.replace('|FFFFFF|000000','|374D7E|FFFFFF')
                                });
                            }                         

                          var letter = context.tag[0];
                          marker.setOptions({
                             icon : '//chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=' + letter + '|FFFFFF|000000'
                          });

                          Map.currentMarker = marker;

                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        };
        Map.init();
    });
})(jQuery);
```